# How to connect UILabel text to UISlider meaning?

Tags: swift, uilabel, swift5, uislider

I'm new in Swift and trying to create Temperature Converter from ºC to ºF programmatically. But I have no idea how to change meaning of my label when l drag the slider.

I tried to change addTarget, but it didn't help. I really have no idea what's wrong and why my label still being "0ºC".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPogs.png)

Here is my code:

---

```
class ListVC: UIViewController {

var cLabel : UILabel = UILabel()
var slider : UISlider = UISlider()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

**// creating label**

let cLabel = UILabel()
    cLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 250, width: 100, height: 200)
    cLabel.textAlignment = .center
    cLabel.text = "0ºC"
    cLabel.textColor = .black
    cLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Apple SD Gothic Neo", size: 25)
   
    
    self.view.addSubview(cLabel)
    self.view = view
    
    
    **// creating slider**
    
    let slider = UISlider()
    slider.frame = CGRect(x: 110, y: 300, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 250)
    slider.center = self.view.center
    slider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    slider.minimumValue = 0
    slider.maximumValue = 100
    slider.value = 0
    slider.isContinuous = true
    slider.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    
    
    slider.addTarget(self, action:#selector(sliderValue(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
  
    self.view.addSubview(slider)

}

**// creating function that had to change label value but something went wrong**

@objc func sliderValue(sender: UISlider) {

cLabel.text = String(sender.value)

    
}
```

---

Thank you!

Comment: That's strange, because you declare a property `var cLabel : UILabel = UILabel()`, but it's not the same as the one in `viewDidLoad()`, you don't. They aren't related. Same for the slider.

Comment: OMG, thank you so much, now it works! I just leave this declarations in Class, and don't repeat them in viewDidLoad.